# Handshake failure when connecting to URL through HttpsURLConnection (Java) but not through CURL?

Tags: java, ssl, handshake

I am writing a client code to connect to a server (which is not under my control). The people who maintain the application on server have provided me a .crt and .key file. I used these and created my own keystore.

When I use the said keystore with CURL utility I am able to establish connection with the host URL. But when I load the keystore into KeyManagerFactory and use it in HttpsURLConnection I get "handshake failure" alert.

I have checked the internet and found something about cipher suites not matching between Server and Client could cause this. But I have tried every suite that I have and it yields the same result. I think the keystore should not be a problem, because CURL when using it is able to connect and if I try connecting without using the keystore even CURL utility fails. So the keystore should be correct.

One thing I noticed is that when I do getLocalCertificates() I always get a null. Does this mean that none of my certificates are being sent to the server? Is my Java code rejecting the certs that I have in my keystore? What could be the reasons for this to happen? Is there anyway I can confirm that this is what is happening?

When I do getServerCertificates() I get 5 certs returned, but getLocalCertificates() is always null.

Another odd thing is that when I send a request to the same URL through Postman, the server responds! I did not even use any keystore or something similar to it, does Postman have its own keystore/cert which is authorized?

I have a strong hunch that getLocalCertificates() being null is the reason my Java code is tanking, but hunches aren't helping me.

Answers which can help me identify or isolate the problem would be great. Well, at this point I would take any guidance and work on it.

Comment: [run with sysprop `javax.net.debug=ssl`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#Debug) and look (1) does the keyentry from your keystore load as intended (2) does its cert match the server CertReq